# Jmeter Post URL with colon

Tags: jmeter, jsessionid

I have a form action that calls the following url :

https://someurl:jsessionid=0000000

The form works.

When trying to mimic it in Jmeter the http request
if I call that url, the server will return that the url does not exists (because the :jsessionid....)

Is there anyway to mimic a form with this kind of url?

Thanks a lot in advance!.

Comment: What's in "someurl", how do you specify it, in which sampler, and how does URL look in JMeter's result tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp), colon (:) can be replaced with %3A. So, you can try this in your HTTP Request:

[image]

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you URL is not correct as colon in URLs can be used only in 2 cases:

1. As a part of URL scheme, i.e. in the end of `http:` or `https:` protocol
2. As a separator between username and password when basic HTTP authentication is used like `http://username:password@server/path`

If you passing JSESSIONID as a parameter - semicolon `;` should be used so please double check the character. If it something coming from the server - raise an issue as colon is not the right separator. If it is something introduced by you - you need to change the colon to semicolon.Normally you should be using either [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier) or [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to correlate the JSESSIONID cookie.